# Can I clone a view but keep it independent of it's content?

Tags: views

I'm looking to duplicate(clone) of a view, so that I may reuse it on other pages and have it will not pull through the same content.

I'm using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) 7.x-3.8 on Drupal 7.34 this will be updated later when the site goes live.

Comment: Yes, you can edit a view after you've cloned it and change what you need to. Depending on your use case a single view with a contextual filter might make more sense though

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to duplicate a `views` as much as you need and edit them independently. It saves a lot of work and time.